# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Just wanted to know if some light could be shed on why my question was closed?

I understand it was perceived as vague, however I don't believe that this is the case-

[I'm buying my first PIC, what kit do I need?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/im-buying-my-first-pic-what-kit-do-i-need)

Considering that other users had tried to answer my question, or had expressed an interest in an answer- I believe my question was closed because of the opinion of an individual user who misinterpreted my question, and then (after commenting) did not give me the benefit of the doubt, or the opportunity to address his criticism.

Comment: you will get a thorough answer but I would like to point out it was not just one user, it was a community moderator. They were elected by the community for knowledge of the system and dedication to it. It is a bit more than the opinion of one user.

Comment: yeah I know that now, I didn't recognise Kevin's name, obviously he's changed it from reemrevnivek. I actually helped to vote him in. I'm starting to feel he's become quite heavy handed with the role of community moderator.

Comment: @Kortuk - just like any democratic representation this is not perfect. I may find that moderator X has good judgement, but that doesn't mean that I *always* will agree with her. It remains a fact that closing by a moderator can be a one person decision (like in this question). Something for reflection: should a single person (moderator) be able to close a question which has 10 upvotes and as many answers?

Comment: I've seen much more vague questions amended an answered on this forum, why not give me the opportunity to address his criticism?- I just don't feel it's fair to close it without anyone else's word or opinion. Kevin Vermeer, why were you so quick to judge? were you that certain the question had no value for the electronics.stackexchange?

Comment: @Jim - I sometimes disagree with closing too, but closing is not permanent! Granted, it prevents new answers, but it also avoids downvotes. Fix your question and flag for moderator's attention, and it will most likely be reopened.

Comment: Cheers- I'll check that out :)

Comment: @Jim, I would have closed it on view also, he closed it quickly as you have something you are doing and you want an open ended list of items you should get. This is not a question with a "correct" answer.

Comment: @stevenvh, we spend a large amount of time just keeping up with the SE community moderators and SE employees, we will very rarely have to lock a 10 upvote question that is a bad quesiton but already has a large number of answer people have put time into. This stops the question continuing to propagate but does not remove the reward for those that already put a large amount of work in. A terrible question with 10 upvotes would still be closed. They do not receive 10 upvotes so it is not a major issue, it was earlier in the site before users were used to the SE system.

Comment: @Jim, it is currently reopened. If the answers are of high quality I think it can work. This is a very boundary question. If the answers all start popping up as very poor that verifies the original belief that the question is too subjective(not constructive). Please do remember that closing is very easy to reverse which is why on a question that clearly does not meet requirements we just close.

Comment: @Kortuk - Thx for that, however I reserve the right to disagree with the statement that I was asking a question that would generate 'an open ended list of items' It's not like an opinion - the list of equipment would not be exhaustive by a long shot. Also  I simply don't appreciate the gesture of having my questions closed, I don't feel I should have to appeal after the fact. I can address a commented criticism myself, a closed question requires a moderator to reinstate it- as if I'm incapable of addressing a little critique.

Comment: @Jim - If we would introduce the right to appeal we'll get endless discussions and no questions would ever be closed. I don't think we should go that far. Like Kortuk and I said, closing can easily be reversed.

Comment: @Jim, there is one thing that is very different from our end. Closing is very quick and you can flag when you want it changed. If I leave a comment and someone does not improve it are they going to flag me to tell me I still need to close it? I used(a long time ago) always leave a comment and check back. It was almost always fruitless and I can easily lose the question to be reminded of it months later when someone considers it reason for their question being acceptable.

Comment: @Jim, there is no harm in disagreeing with me, and I am open to discussion, but if you would like to discuss a decision I am very easy to reach in chat and it is very easy in chat to ask me questions and understand our stance easier. No worries. We will watch this one and see how it goes. Thanks for the support @stevenvh, many people do not realize that we use close knowing we can reverse it the next day with a change to the question.

Comment: @Kortuk - Maybe the confusion stems from that for some people the word "close" sounds like something permanent. Isn't "lock" a better term?

Comment: @Stevenvh, I can see your logic. Lock is a different function though. We intend to leave a locked question around forever. A closed question that is not corrected will be deleted in the longer term.

Answer (score 2):

Re-word your question to be a little more specific and we'll see if we can get it re-opened. As it stands now it is too open-ended to answer 'correctly'.

If you include details about exactly which PIC you are looking at using, what you are looking to do with it, etc, we can better give a definite answer. Either that or chat may be a better place for the more woolly open ended questions.

Comment: I think you'll find that I have mentioned the specific PIC I intend to buy (dsPIC33F), I have also mention what I intend to use it for (Audio Synth) I personally don't think it's open-ended. I've mentioned what computer / OS and ports I have available, I think it's quite implicit that I want to know what software and hardware I'll require to program it. If I need to amend the question to make these points more obvious, then so be it, but on a personal level- I feel this is heavy handed and pedantic

Comment: The dsPIC33 is a family not a specific chip. Different chips in the same family can have very different quirks and requirements

Comment: I see- that's my fault for being outside of the loop, I assumed that was a specific chip, I'll have a look through them and get back to you after I've got my van fixed.

Comment: @ Matt - Scrub that, you already gave me a fantastic answer with all the info I'll need to get started - cheers

Answer (score 1):

This question is meeting multiple close reasons. If you view the [FAQ on "don't ask"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) you will see the reasons it was closed.

It meets both of the following criteria, some more then others:

- Every answer is equally valid:
  “What’s your favorite ______?”
- There is no actual problem to be
  solved: “I’m curious if other people
  feel like I do.”

You are asking what people think you should get, this is an opinion. It is also asking what people think you should have, there is not a real problem here, just a form of shopping advice.

Comment: I can see how you might assume my question meets these criteria. I assure you that the question wasn't asked with the intention of working out people's favourite method or equipment, as a complete newcomer to the world of PIC Microchips, I was simply trying to ascertain a single method from a perspective of total ignorance, I did not want to know how people feel about a given method as 'the best way'

Comment: Thx for the clarification, I appreciate you taking the time

Comment: @Jim, the issue with a post on the internet is that intentions often have little to do with result. I read it and it looked that way, hopefully this has stirred up enough involvement to get you great answers.